# Preserve content after elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Symfony2 website running on Amazon EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk. Each time I deploy a git version of my project immediately lost the contents of a folder ("/web/uploads")

Is there a way to tell to Elastic Beanstalk that this content shouldn´t be overriden?

I was thinking on specify an extra command on container_commands parameter inside my .ebextention file but I´m not sure it is the best way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't preserve that content.  You will need to store it externally in a location such as S3, RDS, DynamoDB, etc.  The other thing about Elastic Beanstalk to note is that if it scales up another instance of your app it won't have the content you stored locally and won't have access to it.  I know it sounds harsh and limiting, but having an automated config/deploy is less trouble in the long run, IMHO. ;)